# How do I stop continuous downgrading by APT?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, downgrade

Every time I go to terminal and do an update+upgrade it wants to downgrade 2 packages (`debhelper` and `dh-autoreconf`).

This is the message I get:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  debhelper dh-autoreconf
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/854 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

The first few times I went ahead with it but then immediately after it has done this it checks the packages and asks me to downgrade those same two packages. Yesterday I was trying to install an Epson scanner and installed a few things (sane and iscan among them). I have tried reinstalling both of the packages it wants to downgrade (using synaptic package manager) but as soon as I did this synaptic marked them for downgrading. What do I do? Should I remove them completely?

Comment: apparently something needs the older versions

Comment: pls update your question with a paste of the messages from the terminal ... highlight to copy hit ctrl-shift-c   then the normal paste   ctrl-v

Comment: @Scott Stensland: I have updated my question with the message but I'm not sure what can be learnt from it.                                 ravery: Is there any way of finding out what needs them?

Comment: Is it safe to remove these packages? I'm just wondering if that would solve it.