# Downgrade package loop

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm having same issue as this. [How do I stop continuous downgrading by APT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961938/how-do-i-stop-continuous-downgrading-by-apt)

Each time I sudo apt update the output is:

```
Ign:1 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease  
Ign:2 http ://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                    
Hit:3 http ://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                     
Ign:4 http ://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease               
Hit:5 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:6 http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:7 http ://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release                      
Hit:8 http ://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release                 
Get:9 http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:11 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                    
Hit:12 http ://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Get:13 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:16 http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB] 
Hit:17 http ://ppa.launchpad.net/rednotebook/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:18 http ://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Fetched 306 kB in 2s (146 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http ://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

__  [links intentionally broken so I can post this without warnings because my reputation is too low]__

And each sudo apt upgrade yields:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Calculating upgrade... Done  
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:  
  debhelper dh-autoreconf  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
Need to get 854 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
Get:1 http ://ppa.launchpad.net/rednotebook/stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 dh-autoreconf all 12~ubuntu16.04.1 [16.0 kB]  
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rednotebook/stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 debhelper all 10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1 [838 kB]  
Fetched 854 kB in 1s (480 kB/s)    
(Reading database ... 300410 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../dh-autoreconf_12~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking dh-autoreconf (12~ubuntu16.04.1) over (12~ubuntu16.04.1) ...  
Preparing to unpack .../debhelper_10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking debhelper (10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...  
Setting up dh-autoreconf (12~ubuntu16.04.1) ...  
Setting up debhelper (10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...  
rdafg@rdafg-multimade:~/Desktop$
```

Is there something I can do to remove the two packages that keep coming up as "to be downgraded."

Thanks

Comment: Please copy/paste as text the output from commands.  Pictures are much harder for to read.

Comment: Well... the issue appears to have fixed itself...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for installed packages that have the exact same version available in multiple apt sources.  apt doesn't track which source you installed a package from, and depending on the order of your apt sources, it can lead to this odd behavior.